# Querying on tables, in different databases, on same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I ran two queries that I came across and they both seemed to have returned different results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Log].[dbo].[LogTable] AS MainLog, [Archive].[dbo].[LogTable] 
ORDER BY [Log].[dbo].[LogTable] DESC;

SELECT * 
FROM [Log].[dbo].[LogTable] 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Archive].[dbo].[LogTable] 
ORDER BY [Log].[dbo].[LogTable] DESC;
```

The second query returned the correct number of rows. It also ordered correctly too. The first query brought back a lot of rows, what exactly did the first query do? It didn't error and it did combine the data.

Comment: The first query was essentially a CROSS JOIN  see http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying how and what columns to join on, you are performing a cross-join. The second query is selecting the records from each table and concatenating the results together.

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting in query one is called Cartesian product. Let's read your query step by step.

Access two databases.

Join LogTable in Archive and Log database.

No Where clause or Join on Condition makes way for Cross join

Cross Join means if you have a,b,c in Log and 1,2,3 in Archive DB. O/P will be a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3. (of course row wise)

Where as in second query you are just writing o/p of two statements one after the other. a,b,c,1,2,3